# swift, convert NSIndexpath to Int

Tags: arrays, uitableview, int, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a tableview with a button in each cell. When that is tapped I have a didselectrow function. I want to use my indexpath to get a value from an array that gives the cells contents. How can I convert this NSIndexpath to an int to use in the array?

Comment: indexPath.Row. IndexPath is an NSIndexPath.

Answer (score 11):

Most likely what you want is the **row** property. You can see an [example here](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/07/a-minimum-viable-tableview-in-swift).

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Item selected", message: "You selected item \(indexPath.row)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                                  style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                                handler: {
                                    (alert: UIAlertAction!) in println("An alert of type \(alert.style.hashValue) was tapped!")
                                }))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Ironically, I discovered your question while looking for the answer to this myself.

Answer (score 2):

Use IndexPath.row, see below for example.

**Ref** (IndexPath:316-319)

```
/// The row of this index path, when used with `UITableView`.
///
/// - precondition: The index path must have exactly two elements.
public var row: Int
```

**Example**

```
let name : String = (indexPath.row>0) ? "Bob" : "Sam";
```

**Reference**

- [IndexPath - Foundation | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexpath)
- [row - IndexPath | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexpath/1779554-row)